# How to synchronize image transitions of ray traced image and swapchain image in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I am very much a Vulkan/ graphics APIs beginner. I've read some resources on Vulkan synchronization and understand it more than at the beginning but the code still doesn't work. I'm expecting the ray tracing pipeline to output a flat color bule image, but it flickers intensly between blue and just black. Validation layers scream every frame that "images passed to present must be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHARED_PRESENT_KHR but is in VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED."

This is more or less what my code looks like:

```cpp
vkBeginCommandBuffer();
// ... bind pipeline and descriptor sets
vkCmdTraceRaysKHR();

        // Prepare current swap chain image as transfer destination
        VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
        barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
        barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.image = swapchainImage;
        barrier.subresourceRange = subresource_range;
        // No need to make anything available
        barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
        // The result of this transition should be visible for transfers
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT | VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT; 

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
            cmdBuffer,
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, // No need to wait for anything
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,    // Should make transfers wait
            0,
            0, nullptr,
            0, nullptr,
            1, &barrier
        );

        // Prepare ray tracing output image as transfer source
        VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
        barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;
        barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.image = renderImage.image;
        barrier.subresourceRange = subresource_range;
        // The data written by the ray tracing should be made available
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT;
        // The transition and data should be visible for transitions
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT | VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
            cmdBuffer,
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_RAY_TRACING_SHADER_BIT_KHR, // Should wait until ray tracing is done
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,               // Should make transfers wait
            0,
            0, nullptr,
            0, nullptr,
            1, &barrier
        );

vkCmdCopyImage();

        // Transition swap chain image back for presentation
        VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
        barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
        barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.image = swapchainImage;
        barrier.subresourceRange = subresource_range;
        // The effects of the transfer should be made available
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
        // The effects of the transfer should be made visible for swapchain presentation
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
            cmdBuffer,
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,      // Wait for transfers
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT,  // Block all commands after this barrier
            0,
            0, nullptr,
            0, nullptr,
            1, &barrier
        );

        // Transition ray tracing output image back to general layout
        VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
        barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;
        barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.image = renderImage.image;
        barrier.subresourceRange = subresource_range;
        // The effects of the transfer should be made available (possibly unnecessary?)
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
        // (possibly unnecessary?)
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT;

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
            cmdBuffer,
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,      // Wait for transfers
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT,  // Block all commands after this barrier
            0,
            0, nullptr,
            0, nullptr,
            1, &barrier
        );
```

After all this the queue is submitted with two semaphores:

- one wait semaphore that is signalled by vkAcquireNextImageKHR. It's wait stage is set to VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_RAY_TRACING_SHADER_BIT_KHR.
- one signal semaphore that is later used as a wait semaphore in vkQueuePresentKHR.

So how do I get rid of the vulkan validation layer message and properly display the rendered image?

**Edit:** The culrpit was found somwhere else (choosing wrong swapchain image for rendering), but I would still appreciate it if someone could confirm/correct my rationale behind the chosen stage and access masks. Especially that now I can't even make it freak out on purpouse, for example by setting the semaphore wait stage to BOTTOM_OF_PIPE (I thought it would mean that no stages wait so the render runs and writes without a swapchain image)

Comment: Did you try to use `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` instead of `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_RAY_TRACING_SHADER_BIT_KHR` in waiting stage in `vkQueueSubmit`?

Comment: Yes, It was initially setup like that because the code around the buffer recording was written for a regular rasterization graphics pipeline. Now I just created the RT pipeline and replaced the command recording for rasterization woth recording for RT

Comment: Make sense, however you execute copy commands and state transitions after finishing RT pipeline. Probably, `vkQueueSubmit` was unleashed a bit earlier than it’s required. 
I’d recommend to play with different waiting stage flags

Comment: Alllllrightt, I just realized it isn't the fault of complex synchronization dependencies, I was just choosing the swapchain image not based on index provided by swapchain but based on an index representing the current frame in flight. ygh... Still however, I would appreciate it if someone could confirm/correct my rationale behind the chosen stage and access masks. Especially that now I can't even make it freak out on purpouse, for example by setting the semaphore wait stage to BOTTOM_OF_PIPE (I thought it would mean that no stages wait so the render runs and writes without  a swapchain image)